# emacs CUA mode Control-C not working

Tags: emacs

I have CUA mode enabled for gnu emacs 23.1.1 on RHEL.  CTL-V and CTL-X are working just as advertised. However CTL-C does not work. I need to use Meta-w.

The problem is my fingers have it so ingrained to do CTL-c.  I really could use this working. Is there

- a known bug for this
- any workaround

Comment: Are you stating that `C-c` in `cua-mode` does *not* copy the selected region?

Comment: that is correct

Comment: I only have 23.4 rather 23.1 at hand, but I can't reproduce this problem.  My guess is that your problem is linked to some other customization.  Try to start `emacs -Q` then `M-x cua-mode` and try to reproduce the problem.